# Can't call a previously declared dictionary though a method

Tags: python-3.x

I'm fairly new to python...aka just started.
So i was making a simple game and i'm trying to get a dictionary to work through out a claas and cant get it to work.

```
class Map(object):
   def __init__(self):
    self.Eng = {
        "1": "Map_Eng()",
        "2": "Guard_Fight()",
        "3": "Item_Eng()"
               }

    def enter_room(self):
        pass

    def exit_room(self):
        print("You move onto the next room.")
        return self.Eng[1]
```

Comment: i get : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Eng'

Comment: How are you using Map class? Show us your code that uses it.

Comment: so far i haven't called it anywhere...i just started using it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is small. Your dictionary has an entry with key `"1"` (a string), but not with key `1` (a number). To fix your problem, change the line

```
return self.Eng[1]
```

to

```
return self.Eng["1"]
```

Comment: i get: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Eng'

Comment: Running this in both python versions it works. Are you sure your indentation is correct?

Comment: I forgot to create a object out of it... i was calling it directly as map.exit_scene instead of m = map and then m.exit_scene